# Selenium WebDriver Report Generation using Allure Reporting tool

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, allure

I am new to Selenium WebDriver.I am currently using TestNg to generate reports .but i need to use Allure Reporting framework with TestNg to generate reports.I don't see any proper documentation for using Allure.Need help in installation and setting up Allure framework with TestNg.

Comment: Access demo directly, its in beta : https://vigoreport.io/login?request=demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any specific reason for using Allure Reports.

I am using [Extent Reports](http://relevantcodes.com/extentreports-for-selenium/)  for my test these are very easy and very good at the same time. 
Here is a sample extent report for selenium tests : [Sample](http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports/Extent.html)

Comment: Thanks, Can Extent Report work with all popular testing frameworks like Testng,Junit,Cucumber? or is it very particular to TestNg?

Comment: Although I have implemented it with TestNG, but i think you can implement using Junit and other frameworks also. Because it depends where you want to initialize your reports and where you want to indicate starting of test. So i guess you can use it popular testing frameworks.

Comment: But I think it's very particular to TestNg framework.I need a reporting tool which will work fine with all popular testing frameworks

Comment: the library seems to be agnostic to test frameworks so you can use anything. there is also a junit example: http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/2x/docs.html#basic-junit-example

Comment: You can even use this library with .Net also:  http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/net/docs.html

Comment: Thanks Karthik,san1deep2set3hi .Then I will proceed with ExtendReport.Can you give the link where I can find the proper installation and implementation of ExtendedReport.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following pages:

- [Main documentation](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki)
- [Maven example](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example)
- [Ant example](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-ant-testng-example)
- [Gradle example](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-gradle-testng-example)